# Self-hosted wiki

Tags: document-management, wiki

I am looking for a wiki solution for managing documentation with these features:

- Self-hosted.
- Supports editing in both WYSIWYG and markdown.
- Supports multiple users.
- Easy to use for both developers and non-technical users.

In particular, I am looking for comparisons between [Outline](https://www.getoutline.com/) and [Dokuwiki](https://www.dokuwiki.org/dokuwiki).

Comment: Have a look here for a comparison for various wikis https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_wiki_software  But just google Outline vs Dokuwiki for direct comparison